# How to get DynamicReports(JasperReports) to show on client side

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I am using DynamicReports which uses Jasper Reports in a web application I am making. I got it to work and all seemed good until I noticed that when I closed the Jasper Viewer it stopped my tomcat server. Upon further investigation I found out that the viewer (Java Desktop App) is just showing on my machine because it's also the server machine and doing it on a remote client, the pdf viewer is still showing on my server machine.

Is there a good way to get jasper reports to show on the client computer with a web app?

Or is there a good alternative framework to generate reports and either embed them in JSP or download to the clients machine?

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Complete your question with examples or schemas.

Comment: You don't use Jasper Viewer for deployment in the web. Usually the file will be created and provided as a PDF file for example. Jasper Viewer is for development or for use inside a desktop application.

Comment: @tobi6 do you have a suggestion for a report generator framework for a web application?

Comment: Well, you are on the right way. Jasper can provide all this. There is loads of documentation for integration in Java projects. Unfortunately I don't code this myself.

Comment: @Kalkrin checkout jasper report server, or do your own application where people can select format and then you export and send the report to browser

Answer (score 0):

May be it's a bit late to answer the question. But may be the others need help to.
So, I used DynamicReports in my projects with java and jsf. What you need to do is, convert the report object into PDF, Excel or HTML format and display it in webbrowser with url (PDF and HTML), or download it for Excel format. So, the DynamicReports will not open the JasperViewer (don't use report.show() -> it will open JasperViewer in local machine).

OR alternative what you can also do, create desktop application to receive jasper report object through websocket communication and print direct to default printer.

If there are others ways, may be someone can share it.

Unfortunately, DynamicReports project is discountinued or down somehow. May be it's time to find an other alternative, because there is no further development. The reachable site https://github.com/dynamicreports/dynamicreports and https://dynamicreports.lbayer.com/

I hope it can help.